# Would you be able to give up everything you own and follow Jesus?

Tags: nature-of-god

Would you be able to give up everything you own and follow Jesus?
Our will is not enough for salvation, instead the Grace of God and the Sacrifice of Jesus and our belief in him.
But, however, our actions and our own will which dictate our works will be judged, examples our transgressions and sins and good deeds.
Therefore, is life just to be lived for pleasure and is ignorance really bliss? Or is the limited time we have on earth a test back to God?
Our world is all about material on earth and human nature cannot get enough wealth (temptation and greed which corrupt), one of my favorite verses in the New Testament is -

Matthew 19:21-24 King James Version (KJV)
Jesus said unto him, If thou wilt be perfect, go and sell that thou hast, and give to the poor, and thou shalt have treasure in heaven: and come and follow me. But when the young man heard that saying, he went away sorrowful: for he had great possessions. Then said Jesus unto his disciples, Verily I say unto you, That a rich man shall hardly enter into the kingdom of heaven. And again I say unto you, It is easier for a camel to go through the eye of a needle, than for a rich man to enter into the kingdom of God.
In the movie the Greatest Story Ever Told the reply was 'who could do such a thing?"

Comment: Everything is relative. Jesus told Zacchaeus that salvation had come to his house after being told by Zacchaeus that he would give half of his belongings to the poor.  That is relatively less than having to give away everything to achieve salvation, like seemingly Lazarus had to to.

Comment: God being my help and strength, yes.  Without His help? No.

Answer (score 1):

If life was a test to see if we were worthy enough to get to heaven, would anybody get to heaven? Given inclusion of that text in  Matthew 19:21-24, that is a valid question, because Jesus implied that the lure and temptations of materialism (great wealth) would prevent entry. When the disciples exclaimed "Who then can be saved?" Jesus replied "With men this is impossible but with God all things are possible". Never mind what any movie says about that! Stick to Jesus' own words!

Soteriology is the Christian doctrine of salvation, so the need is to see what the Christian doctrine of salvation states. The trouble is, there are two basic views on how people can be saved (the understanding with all mainstream Christian denominations being that those saved will get to be with Christ in heaven.) There is what is called Monergism, and then there is Synergism, so that needs to be spelled out first.

**Monergism** (one working) holds that God saves sinners without their assistance.

**Synergism** (working together) teaches that salvation depends on our co-operation.

Protestantism largely says that humans are born in sin, and are incapable of any movement toward God apart from his grace. The Reformed traditions teach that God not only gives sufficient grace for us to cooperate toward our own (spiritual) rebirth but actually grants the new birth and faith prior to any human decision or activity. Rebirth, therefore, is the one working of God - monogeristic.

> "With respect to the doctrine of salvation (soteriology), it is this
> single point that most decisively distinguishes the churches of the
> Reformation from all other traditions... However, monergism teaches
> that God's grace accomplishes everything, even granting us repentance
> and faith." *Pilgrim Theology*, pp 250-1, Michael Horton, Zondervan
> 2011

The same writer in the book just quoted explains what binds, and prevents, people from proving themselves worthy of heaven:

> "Our will can choose only that in which our nature delights. If our
> nature is in bondage to unbelief, then our will is not free with
> respect to God. By nature, we 'by [our] unrighteousness suppress the
> truth' (Ro 1:18). 'Are we Jews any better off? No, not at all; for we
> have already charged that all, both Jews and Greeks, are under sin, as
> it is written, 'None is righteous, no, not one; no one understands; no
> one seeks for God' (Ro 3:9-11). The fallen mind is darkened to the
> gospel apart from the Spirit's gift of faith (1 Co 2:14)... We are
> saved ***for*** works, not ***by*** works (v.10)." *Ibid.* p. 249

Nor will it do to say that, once God has saved us, as a totally unmerited act of grace, we can then start piling up a heap of good works that will show we deserve heaven. No, for that would deny that God's grace is unmerited, that we "were dead in the trespasses and sins in which [we] once walked... But God, being rich in mercy, because of the great love with which he loved us, even when we were dead in our trespasses, made us alive together with Christ (Eph 2:1-2, 4-5).

> "Even so then at this present time also there is a remnant according
> to the election of grace. And if by grace, then it is no more of
> works; otherwise grace is no more grace. But if it be of works, then
> is it no more grace: otherwise work is no more work." Romans 10:5-6
> A.V.

That last quote from the Bible sums it up. And **it helps explain why Jesus set the bar for heaven so impossibly high for humans. Only God can do the impossible and save sinners**. Once he has saved us, with heaven as our final destination, we see how we are saved ***for*** good works, not ***by*** good works. Nothing we can do can ever make us 'worthy' for heaven; only what Christ has freely done for us meets the requirements of perfection needed to get into heaven. That is the monergistic answer to the question.